# Convert PHP/Mysql/Javascript livesearch and verifying input form to Codeigniter MVC

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I'm still confusing about Codeigniter MVC. What I learh for few fast days:
Models: all about database.
Controller: user use it to connect with models.
Views: user see it when using controller for what he/she want.

I have flat php file. I'm using it to search, verify and input. I was suceed to convert input form, so now I can use input form via CI. But, I'm confusing how to convert search and verify part. I need input form (let say: id_member) to (live) search from Mysql. Then, I need input form to be verified whether it's in Mysql or not. If yes, do input. If no, give a warning in the same form (via javascript, maybe?).

Here is my former flat php code, part of verifying the form (verify.php):

```
if (empty($_POST["id_member"]) || empty($_POST["balance"])){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Input valid Member ID and balance!!</div>";  
} else {

    if (empty($idcek)) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'> Member ID:'$_POST[id_member]' not in DB. Use Valid Member ID!</div>";
    } else {
        if($cekdep['act']) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Input balance for '$_POST[id_member]' = '$bal' already succeed. You can only input balance once for same member and same balance in one day.</div>";
        } else {
            if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Balance input success: '$_POST[id_member]' for '$bal'.</div>";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want according to your approach will be something like this :

```
if (!$this->validate_id_member($_POST["id_member"])) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Invalid Memeber ID</div>";
        return;
    }
```

and here will be the simple validation function :

```
function validate_id_member($id_member){
    $member_data=$this->db->query("select id from tablename where id='$_POST[id_member]' ")->row();
    if(!$member_data){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I recommend you start using [codeigniter form validation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) instead of doing it manually , it might be harder at first but later all you'll do will be just copy/paste your earlier validation rules .

also I've tried to reshape your conditions to be easily followed up later , will look like this :

```
if (empty($_POST["id_member"]) || empty($_POST["balance"])) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Input valid Member ID and balance!!</div>";
        return;
    }
    if (empty($idcek)) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'> Member ID:'$_POST[id_member]' not in DB. Use Valid Member ID!</div>";
        return;
    }
    if ($cekdep['act']) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Input balance for '$_POST[id_member]' = '$bal' already succeed. You can only input balance once for same member and same balance in one day.</div>";
        return;
    }
    if ($conn -> multi_query($sql) !== TRUE) {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn -> error;
        return;
    }
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Balance input success: '$_POST[id_member]' for '$bal'.</div>";
```

Comment: Thanks aemad. 
Is it ok to put database script in controller?
I think it should be in models. But for callback, in user guide it should placed at controller?

I just try put mysql script in models, but I don't know how to get callback from it.

Comment: well codeigniter doesn't restrict you to call database from model , good question though regarding the callback , the answer within this link https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/MY-Form-validation---Callbacks-into-Models